# How to add jar to Google App Engine with Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt, objectify

**BackGround:**
I am using Eclipse Lunar along with the Google App Engine plugin to try and build a website. Everything was going well until I wanted to save some data so I followed the [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/usingdatastore) on using Objectify. I downloaded the Objectify jar and placed it in "/war/WEB-INF/lib/" and then added it to the classpath. I then made a `ObyHelper.java` class as instructed in the tutorial and made a couple of my own test classes (which for now you can assume to contain no errors). I can successfully deploy too.

**The question**
When attempting to load the jsp page that uses Objectify (or any servlet/jsp url for that matter) I get the following error:

```
Uncaught exception from servlet
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyService
```

**What did I do wrong and how should I have added the Objectify jar to the class path?**

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the jars to work in the GAE plugin for eclipse project structure you need to

1) place the jar on the WEB-INF/lib folder (in order for them to be deployed to the cloud)

2) add those jars to the classpath manually in order for eclipse to recognize them on  you local dev environment.

Comment: which jars have you included? were did you get them from?

Answer (score -1):

Have you read the Setup documentation?

https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/Setup

You need the guava jar as well. But really you should use Maven (or Ivy, or Gradle); manually copying jars is very old skool.